# filtering and republishing topic messages from console

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking for a fast and easy way to republish data of a topic filtered in another new topic. I see that implementing a filter could be an interesting alternative. However it needs too much developing infraestructure (pluginlib, a package, some c++ code, etc.). I wonder if there is something simpler like the rostopic echo tool:

```
rostopic echo  /topic_name --filter "{predicate}"
```

It should be something like this:

```
rostopic dup /input_topic /output_topic --filter "{predicate}"
```

In my case I want it to use in combination with rxplot. For instance, reading the tf messages fields filtering by the field: child_frame_id.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51263/filtering-and-republishing-topic-messages-from-console/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2012-12-31

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the rostopic documentation, it appears that you can pipe [filtered echo data](http://ros.org/wiki/rostopic#rostopic_echo) into a [rostopic pub command](http://ros.org/wiki/rostopic#rostopic_pub) to do what you want:

```
$ rostopic echo /topic_name --filter "{predicate}" | rostopic pub /output_topic tf/tfMessage
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2013-01-05**:
wonderful.

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2023-05-25**:
Is it possible to do from the code (i.e. C++)?